# Can Docker image be configured or pushed data runtime from jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, sonarqube

I am planning to pull sonarqube docker image and push the code to docker image and run mvn sonar on that code and generate report. I read through many docker jenkins integration documents and white paper, I didn't come across this scenario, does it mean not possible :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One scenario that comes to my mind is you keep your sonarqube environment.

1. Create your sonarqube environment, and keep it (it can be dockerized you just need to persist some paths in you database container and sonarqube container).
2. Setup email notifications, rules and stuff
3. In your CI, use mvn with sonarqube goal.

You can also use various plugins available, You can find an example approach [here](https://medium.com/devops-process-and-tools/jenkins-configuration-523f6c3d0896).

Comment: I do not want to install sonarqube and its dependencies. I want to try sonarqube docker container for that purpose and would like to pass my build to that image and run code analysis on that and generate report.

Comment: @sunil.kms123 You are not installing, You are running it in a docker container, but not from your CI. You call it with your maven, with sonarqube goal (this step should be done with your ci).

Comment: Thanks @Farhad Farahi, I will go through the link.

Comment: Thanks @Farhad. I followed your suggestion and I can see results. upvoted and answer accepted:)